# Django- Files are not being uploaded in /media/<user> file

Tags: django, python-2.7, file-upload

I am trying to upload file in /media/ folder in my django project name codewar.Here I am creating a independent folder for each user and placing the uploaded files in it. However my files are not being uploaded and I am getting error after submitting the query as

```
TypeError at /index/

an integer is required

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/
Django Version:     1.7
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

an integer is required

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\codewar\codewar\views.py in cust_proc, line 38
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.5
Python Path:    

['C:\\Python27\\codewar',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 16 Feb 2015 17:29:28 +0530
```

my urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from codewar.views import *
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = patterns('',(r'^index/$',mainsite),url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += patterns('',) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import *
from django.http import *
from django.template.loader import *
from django.template import *
from os import *
from os.path import *
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.conf import settings

def mainsite(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        return render_to_response('index.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request,processors=[cust_proc]))
    else:
        return render_to_response('index.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def cust_proc(request):
    data={}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newpath="C:\\Python27\\codewar\\media\\"+request.POST.get('name')
        if not exists(newpath):
            mkdir(newpath)
        #t=save_file(request.POST.get('name'),request.FILES.get('browse'))
        if 'file' in request.FILES:
            file = request.FILES['file']
            print file

            # Other data on the request.FILES dictionary:
            #   filesize = len(file['content'])
            #   filetype = file['content-type']
            dirname=request.POST.get('name')
            filename = request.POST.get('filename')#file['filename']
            s= settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"\\"+dirname+"\\"+filename
            print s
            #fd = open('%s' % (s), 'wb')
            fd=request.FILES['file'].read()

            fdd=open(s,"w")
            ffd.write(fd)
            fdd.close()
            #fd.write(file['content'])


        data={
        'name':request.POST.get('name'),
        'filename':request.POST.get('filename'),
        'code':request.FILES['file'].read()
        }

    return {'data':data}
```

my settings.py  is:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'codewar.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'codewar.wsgi.application'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = "C:\Python27\codewar\static"

TEMPLATE_DIRS=(
    'C:\Python27\codewar',
    )

STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 'C:\Python27\codewar\staticfiles',
)

MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:\Python27\codewar\media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: What's on `line 38` of your views? It's something in the `cust_proc` function...

Comment: `filename = request.POST.get('filename')#file['filename']`

Comment: thats a simple filename retrival from a text area. the file['filename'] is commented and the code is only filename = request.POST.get('filename')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think line 38 is this line:

```
fdd=open(s,"w")
```

Note that you are importing `os.open` using this statement in the beginning of your `views.py`:

```
from os import *
```

In line 38 you are actually trying to call `os.open`. Now, `os.open` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open)) is *different* than built-in `open` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)). It expects an integer mode argument.

You should modify your import line to import only necessary functions from `os` library.

As a side note, wildcard imports are not advised because of namespace pollution causing errors of this kind.

Comment: Thank You so much for the help .. I got the thing working.. I had really been stuck in that since yesterday.. :)